# Dnsmasq block every domain as NXDOMAIN

Tags: dnsmasq

With Dnsmasq version **older than 2.86** I was able to add the directive `address=/#/` to dnsmasq.conf and it would *block every query* and mark it as NXDOMAIN exactly as I want it.

Since Dnsmasq 2.86 release this directive no longer works and I use `address=/#/#` instead.
However this marks it as NULL address (0.0.0.0) which I would like to avoid.

I tried with these but was still unsuccessful to get an NXDOMAIN return:

```
server=/#/
server=/#/#
local=/#/
local=/#/#
```

The Dnsmasq man page describes the changed behavior in newer version but I cannot recreate what I had with older versions.